# MySQL aggregation and separation at the same time

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

I have this quite complex problem I guess. My Mysql DB looks like that:

Trips:

- id
- mileage
- car id
- driver id

Drivers:

- id
- name

Cars:

- id
- model

What I need to achieve is a table aggregating data for a car BUT for separate drivers, so it could look like this:

- Car: total mileage, ... (of this car, all drivers total)
  - Driver: total mileage, ... (of this car, X1 driver only)
  - Driver: total mileage, ... (of this car, X2 driver only)

- Car: total mileage, ... (of this car, all drivers total)
  - Driver: total mileage, ... (of this car, X1 driver only)
  - Driver: total mileage, ... (of this car, X2 driver only)

and so on. I got first step done, so I grouped data by car's id. I now need to get same statistics for separate drivers for each car.

Can it be easily done?

Thanks for any help

@EDIT

Current query

```
"SELECT SUM(`przejazdy`.`przebieg`) as przebieg, SUM(`przejazdy`.`norma`) as norma, SUM(`przejazdy`.`faktyczne`) as zuzycie, `wozy`.`nr wozu`, `kierowcy`.`nr kierowcy` FROM `przejazdy` JOIN `wozy` ON `wozy`.`id` = `przejazdy`.`nr wozu` JOIN `kierowcy` ON `kierowcy`.`id` = `przejazdy`.`nr kierowcy` GROUP BY `przejazdy`.`nr wozu`, `przejazdy`.`nr kierowcy` WITH ROLLUP";
```

It returns me a "flat" array, not very useful - I would need 2-level array:

key: car's id -> containing arrays of data with driver's id, mileage and rest of stats and array "total" for total car's data

Comment: done, it work now, I can't figure out how to process the data tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUPING by car-ID and Driver and aggreate by mileage and use the WITH ROLLUP in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT carID, dirverID, sum(mileage) FROM ... GROUP BY 1, 2 WITH ROLUP;
```

Comment: that's great, it works, but the result returned from database makes it very hard to process as it is n-indexed "flat" array. Any idea how to make it work in PHP easily?

Comment: if you make sure that carID and driverID is NOT NULL you can parse each resulting line in PHP. The ROLLUP-lines have a NULL as carID and driverID. Not nice but should do the job.